# Could not load movie file Processing, Library issue?

Tags: java, processing, movie

Essentially I'm trying to load a movie in processing.

the error is 
" Could not load movie file data/test.mov "

I have tried:

- playing a .mov, .mp4, .wmv
- locating the file in various file paths (a folder called data, no folder at all, a folder without certain unicode letters)
  I have triple checked and run multiple tests with just the move file on it's own.

The code I am testing at the moment.

```
import processing.video.*;
Move test;

void setup() {
size(800, 800);
test = new Movie(this, "data/test.mov")
test.loop()
```

the above "test = new Movie" section is where my error occurs

```
void draw(){
background(0);
image(test, 400, 400)
}
```

also been tried without the "image(test, 400, 400)" section.

Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `test = new Movie(this, "test.mov")` while having the `test.mov` file inside `data` folder? Another option could be to try if it works with the absolute path of the file.

Comment: Indeed it did, what a strange thing, thank you so much, did you wanna add that as a answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: Yeah, sure. I can add it as the actual answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to use `new Movie(this, "test.mov")` while having the test.mov file inside data folder. Another option could be to try if it works with the absolute path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type of the variable `test` is of type `Move` and not `Movie`.
Are you sure that it is right.

Comment: Typo sorry, turns out it was mic4ael answer

Comment: In that case It will not even compile.